# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe' with rapsberry Pi

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi3

I know there are similar questions, but none was able to provide me with an answer. I am running a python script on a raspberry pi (model 3). I am using python 3 and pandas is installed trough pip install pandas. My code is able to run the line `import pandas as pd`, but `test = pd.Dataframe` gives me an error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'`

As shown in my code below, I have checked that my code has a proper pandas module.

I also checked directly in python:

```
`Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
```

This works fine:

```
>>> test = pd.Dataframe()
```

But this gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute'{}'".format(name))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'`
```

I checked my folder's name. I have no file called pandas or pd. My rapsberry pi is brand new. The script is the only file in the folder.

A pwd gives me: `/home/pi/sensehat_projects/Raspb_fitbit/rasp_code`

and ls -a:
`.  ..  .DS_Store  weather_script.py`

```
try:
from pip._internal.operations import freeze
except ImportError:  # pip < 10.0
    from pip.operations import freeze

x = freeze.freeze()
for p in x:
    print(p) 

# prints a list of modules (pandas==0.25.0)
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Dataframe()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather_script.py", line 18, in <module>
    data = pd.Dataframe()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```

I believe this code should properly build an empty pandas dataframe.

Comment: Did you try `pd.DataFrame` with a capital F?

Comment: No. I do this directly

Comment: This works thanks a lot! How to spend hours turning in circles!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
```

With a capital ‘F’. 
pd.Dataframe() (without the capital ‘F’) doesn’t exist, so it will throw the error shown.